# Depending on hold the box after close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click to the button and close my box with jQuery ( Toggle ) ,If the box closed I want to box will depend on hold after I refresh the page . Or If it's Open ,after I refresh the page It will stay open.

I don't know the code that help me do what I want .

For example I wrote a code when we click on red Square , the blue square will be disappear and when we click on it again the blue square will be appear . but there is a problem that after I refresh the page My data or changes will be forgotten .
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RitaWeb/pzhgh/)

CSS :

```
.close-open {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
}
.box {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<span class="close-open"></span>
<div class="box">Test Box Toggle</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close-open").click(function(){
    $(".box").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to store that value in the browser to reuse it. Take a look at [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: @blex can you edit my code in fiddle and give the code to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with some ways. I will show one with [Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp):

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isClose = localStorage.getItem("isClose");
    if(isClose == "false"){
        $(".box").hide();
    } 

  $(".close-open").click(function(){
    $(".box").toggle(
        function(){
            localStorage.setItem("isClose", $(this).is(':visible'));
        });
  });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzhgh/19/)

> The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The
>   data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be
>   available the next day, week, or year.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work in fiddle , I mean it has no effect when I click on red box .

Comment: @amn This example works perfectly for me (note that only modern browsers will work with localStorage)

Comment: @blex yeah it works me to , I checked it again with chrome and it worked . Is this code work on mozila firefox too ?

Comment: Updated. Didn't liked my first approach. Same result with better code i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want restrict this functionality to the particular session you can use this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                             if(sessionStorage.isVisible == "false" ){
                                 $(".box").hide();
                                 sessionStorage.isVisible = "true";
                             }
                             else
                                 sessionStorage.isVisible = "false";
  $(".close-open").click(function(){           
    sessionStorage.isVisible = $(".box").toggle().is(':visible');
  });
});
```

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Manirajss/au8u8/1/)